# Get JSON key By Matching sub-object's key value

Tags: php, json

I have a json string:

```
$testArray = 
{
    "Test1": {
        "id": "26",
        "admin": "Admin TestClient"
    },
    "Test2": {
        "id": "27",
        "admin": "Admin TestClient"
    },
    "Test3": {
        "id": "28",
        "admin": "Admin TestClient"
    }
}
```

And a variable with id value, say

```
$idSearch = 28;
```

Now I need to get its key :  "Test3"

I tried :

```
$NameKey = array_search($idSearch , $testArray->id);
```

But this gives null

Comment: `json variable`? No such thing. You might have a json **STRING**, but you shouldn't be searchign in that string. You should be searching in a php data structure created by decoding that json string.

Comment: This seems a JavaScript json variable. Also you need to retrieve parent key of your given id?

Comment: yep json string.. thnx..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, it's better to use a simple loop:

```
function getById($id) {
    foreach ($testArray as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['id'] == $id) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return '';
}

$key = getById(28);
var_dump($key);
```

Comment: that worked great... i need to get more hands-on with json i guess.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
array_reduce($testArray, function ($result, $item) use ($idSearch) {
    return $result ?: ($item['id'] === $idSearch ? $item : null);
});
```