# Json decode using content of array

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, parsing

I'm training myself (JSON and PHP) and I have a problem
I have Json decode look like this :

```
"playerstats": {
    "steamID": "75068112",
    "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
    "stats": [
        {
            "name": "total_kills",
            "value": 2314497
        },
        {
            "name": "total_deaths",
            "value": 1811387
        },
```

And to parse into php i do :

```
$url = 'myrul';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
echo  $json['playerstats']['stats'][1]['name']
```

And it works but the problem is when i change the id to get stats, the order of the array isn't the same :/
So i can't use [2] or any else number to get data.

I post here to know how could'i get stats using the attribute name of each array (`'total_kills'` for example) instead of [1]..[2]..

thanks for all your support

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789350/get-json-key-by-matching-sub-objects-key-value ?

Comment: use foreach($json['playerstats']['stats'] as $row ) { echo $row['name']; echo $row['value']; }

Comment: I tried with for each  and it works but i want only 10 value and the for each return 200 sor it's to high :/
I wanna do it manualy. I realy want to filter by name and return the value of 5names max

Comment: exit the foreach { if(i==10){ break; } } after reach  some condition

Comment: Wiil it work ? Cause I wan't the name and value of the 1st, 2, 55, 64, 121, and 186, but can't use their number to filter, just their name
Sorry but i'm working alone and training by myself so i didn't learn by school :/

Comment: you need 10 values where name is total_kills . is it ? @Lucas

Comment: Sorry i'm not english so it's not easy to explain
The way is : I want stats from CSGO api
I did somethings and it work (using array position) but the fact is when i change the player ID, value or not the same  for exemple : total_kill is 1st with my id but 2st by other id 
So i can't use [1] or else to get value. I have to use the name "total_kills" but i also want "hours_player", "total_moeny" etc..
But i just want 10 things instead of 200 return by foreach :/
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: check my below answer @Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `foreach` and use if condition to check the name is  `'total_kills'` is true then store it into new array like this .

```
    <?php
    $json = json_decode($content, true);
    $new_array =array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($json['playerstats']['stats'] as $row )
    { 

        if($row['name']=='total_kills')
        {

            $new_array[]=array($row['name']=>$row['value']);
        }

        if($i<10)
        {

           break;   
        }
        $i++
    } 

    print_r($new_array);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you ! This work well and i learned way to do things :)
Have a nice day :)

Comment: glad to help you @Lucas

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'myrul';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);  

foreach($json['playerstats']['stats'] as $row )
{ 

 echo $row['name'];
 echo $row['value']; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a way to loop over the array. In PHP you can do the following;

```
$url = 'myurl';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json["playerstats"]["stats"] as $stat){
    if($stat["name"] == "total_kills"){
        echo "total kills: ".$stat["value"];
    }
    elseif($stat["name"] == "total_deaths"){
        // ...
    }
    // etc... continue to select all parameters you would like
}
```

This will allow you to get the `value` for each stat with `name` using the if else statement.

Comment: Thank you, this work ! 
An other answer was post and i chosed it but this helped me too :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do something with all objects in an array is to use the [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function, which takes another function as one of its arguments. Using this whenever you can will force you to adhere to good programming practices, because the passed in function cannot modify values outside of the array and arguments passed in via `use`.